# How can I add text to a background image that fits the size of a browser

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-2012, css-position

I have been asked to greate a simple page for my company, basically it has the company logo as a background image.  The image resizes itself when you change the size of the browser.  I have done this no problem using HTML & CSS.

However, I now need to place some text over the logo and to the right of it, and this text needs to also move to stay in position with the background image if the browser size changes.

How do I do this??  I can use DIV tags to place text in certain positions on the screen no problem, but obviously once the browser size is changed then the text isn't in position relative to the background image.

Any ideas????

I have been stuck on this for hours now and it's starting to annoy me.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

try positioning your div with percent

```
left:50%;
right:50%;
```

Answer (score 0):

To center the div horizontally:

```
div.logo_text
{
    width  : 5 em;
    margin : 0 auto;
}
```

A set width is a necessity.

Alternatively you can do this it also allows off center positioning, as well as vertical alignment:

```
body
{
    min-height  : 100%;
}

div.logo_text
{
    position    : fixed; 
    left        : 33%;
    top         : 33%;
}
```

Would place it at 33% of the screen top of the screen and 33% from the left side always. You also would need to make the size of the text relative to the size of the screen if you want to stick to the dimensions of a logo.

You can use negative margins that have half the value of the DIV's width to center on a position.

```
div.logo_text
{
    position    : fixed; 
    left        : 33%;
    top         : 33%;
    width       : 6em;
    margin-left : -3em;
}
```

I don't think you will succeed in positioning it perfectly this way. You can see into SVG for an image that scales as you zoom. Not all browsers (read IE9 and below) support this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  But I don't get how I use this with my div??  even if I give my div the id of logo_text, this does nothing.  How do I assign these values to my <div>?

Comment: Maybe you should share your HTML code, then maybe we can understand better what it is you're trying to do..